# name or property attribute for Open Graph (meta) tags

Tags: html, facebook, meta-tags

When I read [Facebook's docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/) regarding Open Graph tags, I can see they recommend using the `property` attribute when declaring them. However, in looking at [MDN's references on the meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) it seems the `property` attribute isn't valid.

When I watch [Apple's Safari 15 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10029/), they recommend using the `name` attribute instead. But then Apple also have [docs that conflict that](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2444/_index.html).

Which of the two examples is actually correct:

```html
<!-- Example 1 -->
<meta
  content="My Cool Title"
  name="og:title"
>

<!-- Example 2 -->
<meta
  content="My Cool Title"
  property="og:title"
>
```

Should I be using `name` or `property` with my `<meta>` tags?

Comment: ahrefs says 'property' - twitter says 'name'...